# ESLint throws no-undef even if variable is in IF statement

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I am using React and I am not able to build my application as long as I have undefined variable. I am using that variable only in IF statement (if it's defined, use it).

```js
if (something)
   const newItem = 'wow!';

if (typeof newItem === "undefined")
    console.log('newItem undefined')   
else
    console.log(newItem); //ESLint: Line YY:XX: 'newItem' is not defined  no-undef
```

How can I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `if` statement creates a lexical scope. In fact, any time you see `{}` in javascript, that creates a scope. What that means is that variables declared with `let` or `const` in that scope cannot be accessed outside of that scope.

```
if (something) {
   const newItem = 'wow!';
   // newItem exists here
}
// newItem does not exist here
```

What you want to do is declare the variable in the scope where you want to access it, and then just assign to that variable in your `if` statement:

```
let newItem;
if (something) {
    newItem = 'wow!';
}
// newItem exists here, and has a value of either 'wow!' or undefined.
```

Note that I had to change the variable declaration from `const` to `let` because we need to assign a value to the value after its creation, so it can no longer be a constant.

Comment: Oh yea, I see. My fault. As long as JavaScript creates lexical scope in each closure there is no need for checking variable declaration.